# Do we need wires for current conduction in ionosphere?

Tags: electricity

As we all know in ionosphere there are free ions and electrons present.

So if we somehow take a bulb and a battery in the ionosphere then will the bulb glow due to conducting nature of environment in ionosphere itself without using any wire ?

I know the density of free ions and electrons is low in the ionosphere , then if we somehow create an environment with high density of free charge carriers , then will the same will happen for this case ?

Comment: Welcome Varun. Question marks and punctuation aren't forbidden in this site

Answer (score 1):

Although there are many free ions and electrons, I strongly doubt that it would be sufficient. Consider this: electrons always take the path of least resistance. If the atmosphere was that conductive, then the battery would just short out because the electrons would just go from pole to pole of the battery without going through the bulb.

Comment: i too think so but even then i've some doubt in this question. can you please explain it more.